# Testing for the definedness of a variable in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Besides regular definitions like `(define variable value)` Scheme also allows for uninitialized definitions like `(define variable)`, when the variable is bound to some value later on with the aid of `set!`.

Are there procedures allowing to test whether a symbol is a defined (not necessarily initialized) variable? Something like `(defined? 'variable)` which should return `#t` if `variable` is defined and `#f` otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

The form `(define var)` is a non-standard extension.

According to R5RS `define` has one of the following forms:

```
(define <variable> <expression>)
(define (<variable> <formals>) <body>)
(define (<variable> . <formal>) <body>)
```

As far as I can tell the same goes for R6RS and R7RS.

Most likely `(define foo)` expands to `(define foo the-undefined-value)` in your implementation. This means you can use `(if (eq? foo the-undefined-value) ...) to test whether`foo` is has been initialized or not.

http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_idx_190

Update:

I checked R6RS and it says:

```
(define <variable> <unspecified>)
where <unspecified> is a side-effect-free expression returning 
an unspecified value.
```

Consider

```
(define foo)
(define bar)
```

It is up to the implementor whether the same unspecified value that is bound to both `foo` and `bar`.

Try this program:

```
(define unspecified)
(define unspecified1)
(eq? unspecified unspecified1)
```

If the program evaluates to `#t` then you can write an `initialized?` predicate like this:

```
(define unspecified)
(define (initialized? x) (not (eq? x unspecified)))

(define test)
(initialized? test)
(set! test 42)
(initialized? test)
```

Comment: You have made me curious, so I have checked: in R6RS this form is explicitly mentioned in section 11.2.1; this is the one that I had in mind. Nevertheless, it is absent from the new R7RS.

Comment: @AlexM. I checked r5rs and r7rs and guessed that r6rs was the same. Apparently not.

Comment: @AlexM. I updated the answer. The solution may or may not work on your implementation.

Comment: First, I tried it on Larceny 0.98 (which defaults to R7RS). The syntax `(define a)` was accepted, but the equality test failed (probably because Larceny doesn't know how to evaluate `a`). In fact, just typing `a` produces `Error: undefined global variable: a`. Since `a` *is* defined, I suspect this is a bug: the error is correct, the syntax should not be accepted. Chez 8.4 (which implements R6RS) accepts the syntax and the equality returns `#t`; your code works very well. (Is `42` in your example the meaning of life?)

Comment: Please note, though, that I was asking about testing whether a symbol represents a (defined) variable, not about testing the initialization status of a defined variable, some procedure `defined?` able to query the current environment (viewed as an associative array), examining the keys one by one. Still, your answer has been informative, thank you.

Comment: Note that it should be `unspecified1` instead of `unspecified?`. I do not have enough reputation to correct your answer.

Comment: Fixed the typo. Regarding: :" ... asking about testing whether a symbol represents a (defined) variable ...". A symbol doesn't represent a variable. A symbol is just a name. If you want to know whether a variable with a given name is defined on runtime then *maybe* `eval` can be used - but at best you will get an implementation dependent answer.

Comment: The issue is more complicated. Assume that I have a procedure `defined?` that returns `#t` if its argument is a defined variable and `#f` otherwise. Clearly I cannot use it as `(defined? x)` because `x` may not be defined and I would get an error. Therefore, either I invoke it as `(defined? 'x)` or instead of a procedure I define it as syntax, and thus avoid argument evaluation. Still, even with `define-syntax` I wouldn't know how to construct it. Anyway, since it is not in R7RS, I guess I should stop thinking about it.

Comment: @AlexM. I looked at 11.2.1 and I think it works similar to `if` without consequent. eg. the implementation chooses a value that the variable gets bound to. It is not the same as an unbound variable. Doing `(initialized? test)` where `test` is not defined will have undefined consequences.

Comment: I've lied in a comment above: Larceny 0.98 starts in R5RS mode by default (and since R5RS does not have this syntax for uninitialized definitions, no wonder I've got an error message). It has to be called with the "-r7rs" switch in order to start in R7RS mode.

Comment: I forgot about "The issue is more complicated. Assume that I have a procedure defined? that returns #t if its argument is a defined variable and #f otherwise. " The problem here is that in a call `(defined? x)`  scheme will i) evaluate the reference defined? (and get a procedure value), ii) evaluate the variable reference x and a value v (the one bound to x), iii) the procedure will be called with the value v as argument. This means that a procedure `defined?` doesn't know about the variable `x`.

Answer (score 2):

There is simple universal solution based on try-catch. I've tested it on Gambit v4.9.3.

```
(define (defined? var-symbol)
 (with-exception-handler
  (lambda (e) void)
  (lambda () (not (eq? void (eval var-symbol))))
 )
)
```

And here are the test cases:

```
> (defined? 'a)
#f
> (define a 123)
> (defined? 'a) 
#t
> (defined? 'x)
#f
> (define x)
> (defined? 'x)
#t
> (defined? 'f)
#f
> (define (f a b) (+ a b))
> (defined? 'f)           
#t
```

With this you can make conditional definitions:

```
(define (define-if-not var-symbol init)
 (if (defined? var-symbol) void
  (let ((value (init)))
   (eval (list 'define var-symbol value))
   value
  )
 )
)
```

The tests:

```
> (define a 'abc)
> (define (make-123) 123)
> (define-if-not 'a make-123)
#<procedure #2 void>
> (define-if-not 'b make-123)
123
> a
abc
> b
123
```

This variant of `define-if-not` has a caveat: if the value is a symbol, eval treats it as a reference. This is the short demo:

```
> (define value 123)
> (eval (list 'define 'a value))
> (define value 'abc)           
> (eval (list 'define 'a value))
*** ERROR -- Unbound variable: abc
```

The following [nasty] solution overcomes it for Gambit:

```
(define define-if-not-private)

(define (define-if-not var-symbol init)
 (if (defined? var-symbol) void
  (let ((value (init)))
   (set! define-if-not-private (lambda () value))
   (eval (list 'define var-symbol '(define-if-not-private)))
   value
  )
 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [scheme report (standard)](http://www.r6rs.org/) `define` is used to define a variable. (put it into existence) Using `define` without an expression like `(define test)` defines the variable to some value chosen by the implementation.

It can only be used once in the same scope for the same variable, thus `set!` is to alter an existing variable to something else, but it cannot remove it's existence.

There is nothing in the report to remove a binding or to check if a binding exists. Using a variable without it being defined will have undefined consquences.

Implementations may have feature beyond the report. These things are typically stuff the guts of a scheme system should know about and they may expose it to the user, but it is implementation dependent and not standard.